Docker on Windows 11 is causing high cpu usage and crashing the windows
I did a windows update last night (2024-07 Cumulative Update Preview for Windows 11 Version 23H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5040527))
and after the update docker desktop has stopped working and while starting it causes high cpu usage and eventually crashes whole windows application
Anyone else facing this issue on windows? what can be done to get around it. I need docker on my machine
I simply installed a windows update.
I expected everything to work fine after that.
But docker freezes and crashes windows and that was not the case before
